# How to shift an entire array one position to the right?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void moveRight (int a[], int n){
    int aux;
    for(int i = 1; i<n; i--){
        aux = a[i];
        a[i]= a [i];
    }
}
```

I been trying with this code but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you read the loop condition?

Comment: Why do you think this code would do anything at all?

Comment: Please clarify "it doesn't work".  There are a nearly infinite amount of problems that could lead to that symptom, from "*you're assigning a value to itself*" all the way to "*you forgot to compile your code*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the loop variable is supposed to be going up. so change `i--` to `i++`. Then, if I correctly understand what you're trying to do, you need `a[i] = a[i-1]` in the loop body. instead of `a[i] = a[i]` (which does nothing). Also, you don't need `aux`.

It's not clear what, if anything, you want to happen to `a[0]` when everything moves to the right. That should take place after the loop exits. (If you want the last element to move to the first element position, then I retract my comment about `tmp`; you'll need to store that last element somewhere so it's available after the array element gets overwritten. But it only needs to be stashed once, before the loop starts.)

One other comment: `n` must never be more than `a.length` or the loop will throw an exception. If `n` is always equal to `a.length`, then you can dispense with the argument and just use `a.length` in the method.

Answer (score 7):

When printing the contents of an array, the left starts with the lowest values. If you move the values down the indexes you could say this is to the left. For moving the values up by index you need to start at the end and work down.

```
// Move one up
for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    a[i] = a[i-1];

// Move one down
for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++)
    a[i] = a[i+1];
```

Note: This is likely to be inefficent compare with using `arraycopy` which is designed for bulk array copies.

```
// Move one up
System.arraycopy(a, 0, a, 1, a.length-1);
// Move one down
System.arraycopy(a, 1, a, 0, a.length-1);
```